# PHP SOAP send a element as xsi:type="xsd:boolean"

Tags: php, soap-client

I've searched in the Internet, without success, for a way to add xsi:type="xsd:boolean" to a specific element.. I'm using th soap for PHP, could you please help me?

```
$paramsBody = array("Parametros" => array('Parametro' => array("Name" => 'Todos', 'Value' => new SOAPVar('false', XSD_ANYTYPE, null, null, null, 'http://microsoft.com/webservices/'))));

$this->client->$function($paramsBody);
```

XML Output:

```
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:Export>
         <ns1:Parametros>
            <ns1:Parametro>
               <ns1:Name>Todos</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value>false</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Parametro>
         </ns1:Parametros>
      </ns1:Export>
   </env:Body>
```

How should be...

```
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:Export>
         <ns1:Parametros>
            <ns1:Parametro>
               <ns1:Name>Todos</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Parametro>
         </ns1:Parametros>
      </ns1:Export>
   </env:Body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a soluction with SoapVar object!

```
array("Parametros" => array('Parametro' => array("Name" => 'Todos', "Value" => new SoapVar('true', XSD_STRING, 'xsd:boolean'))))
```